# ActiveRecord update_column: How to increase a record value depending on it's current value with just one query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

The below hits database twice - how do I reduce it to single query?

```
@user = User.find(123)
@user.update_column(:views, @user.views + 1)
```

Something like this:

```
User.find(123).update_column(:views, self.views + 1)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
User.where(id: 123).update_all('views = views + 1')
```

It will produce the following query:

```
UPDATE users SET views = views + 1 WHERE users.id = 123
```

Comment: The other advantage of this is there's no race conditions, this is an atomic update. You can also do this with a singular `update_all` call, the second argument is a scope, but this looks better with `where`.

Answer (score 6):

Rails has a dedicated method [`increment_counter`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-increment_counter) to increment a numeric field by one:

```
User.increment_counter(:views, 123)
# UPDATE `users` SET `views` = COALESCE(`views`, 0) + 1 WHERE `users`.`id` = 123
```

`` COALESCE(`views`, 0) `` ensures that it also works with `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

```
User.connection.execute(%|
  UPDATE users SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = 123
|)
```

Answer (score -2):

`User.find(123).increment(:views)`

see
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment!

Comment: Your answer is, unfortunately, wrong - it does not update the `views` in this query, it only returns the incremented value of `views`. if you do `User.find(123)` it will return the user with non-changed `views` column.